# Force color of listoffigures

Tags: table-of-contents, color, captions

Imagine the following example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \caption{\textcolor{green}{Green} and \textcolor{red}{red}}
    \end{figure}

    \listoffigures
\end{document}
```

It results in a colored caption of the figure:
[image: Figure caption with green and red font]

and a colored entry in the list of figures:
[image: List of figures with green and red font as well]

How can I force the color of the list entry to be black? I was not able to find a macro that overwrites or strips the color of the list entries, because the inner color macros of the caption seem to have a higher priority.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are a couple of options:

### Fairly manual solution

The simplest way would be to use the optional argument of the `caption` command:

```
\caption[<Line for the lof>]{Caption in document}
```

so you could use, for example

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \caption[Green and red]{\textcolor{green}{Green} and \textcolor{red}{red}}
    \end{figure}

    \listoffigures
\end{document}
```

### Not-so manual solution

If you don't want to go through each and every caption (I don't think I would if I were you), then you could change the `color` command locally for the `listoffigures` by using

```
\begingroup
\renewcommand{\color}[1]{}
\listoffigures
\endgroup
```

This makes the `color` command do absolutely nothing within this group, so you simply get black text as required.